# Windows Logo Kit and WHQL for Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, driver-signing

Is it still possible to WHQL-certify drivers for Windows XP, given that it has reached its end of life?

If so, which version of the Windows Logo Kit do I need?
Windows Logo Kit 1.6 won't install on my Windows XP Service Pack 3 machine.

In particular, when I try to install Windows Logo Kit 1.6 on Windows XP with Service Pack 3, I'm unable to install any of the components, with the detail text being:

http://pastebin.com/rWRfMiZy

e.g. things like:

```
   REQUIRED COMPONENT: "EULA" unavailable due to status = Not Installable
      ISSUE: Unsupported OS SKU
         DETAIL: Current OS: Windows XP (Supported OS: Windows Longhorn Server)
      ISSUE: Unsupported CPU Architecture
         DETAIL: Current CPU: x86 (Supported CPU: x64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can still certify *hardware* for XP (but not systems).  WLK 1.6 is the correct version and should install on XP.  See [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487533)

What happens when you try to install it?

**EDIT**: It's been a while since I was involved with WHQL testing, so ignore the information above.  That link is wrong.  I've done some further investigation and here are the facts:

1. The kit can be installed on and run from a Windows 2003 server only.  That is the controller/master box that runs, controls and collects the test info. It also makes the submissions.  You need a second test box running the OS you're certifying for.  It runs as a slave to the server.
2. The only way to certify for XP is to certify for Vista, 2003 or Win7, and then you are automatically approved for XP.

Comment: I've detailed in my original question.

Comment: Hey, there's no Windows Logo Kit 1.7 on Microsoft's site.

Comment: @Ilya: Sorry, I misread a notice on MSDN.  1.6 is still the current release.